# Compiling and interfacing with a C DLL within Python works on Unix, but not Windows. What is the correct way to do this?

Tags: python, c, dll, ctypes

So, I have the following file:

addone.c

```
long int addone(long int x){
     return x+1;
}
```

Which is then compiled into a DLL via a windows installation of GCC 7.2.0 (I've also tried using the Intel C++ compiler, after changing the function to `extern "C" long int addone(long int x)`, but that doesn't change the outcome when I try to load it into Python):

```
gcc -c addone.c
gcc -shared -o addone.dll addone.o
```

Which I then attempt to load into python 3.6.7:

```
import ctypes
_addone = ctypes.CDLL("addone.dll")
```

Although I do manage to get CDLL object, it's missing the function "addone". I've tried using the `ctypes.WinDLL()` and `ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary` methods of importing C DLLs, but these all accomplish the same end result: I get an object from ctypes that possesses no public methods, and none of the private methods (in the Python object, not the DLL) seem to be related to the addone function.

Just to double-check that my compiler is doing what I expect, I disassembled the resulting DLL, which looks like a typical DLL. Inside, the function isn't even name-mangled:

```
0000000530ce1030 <add_one>:
530ce1030:   55                      push   %rbp
530ce1031:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
530ce1034:   48 89 4d 10             mov    %rcx,0x10(%rbp)
530ce1038:   48 8b 45 10             mov    0x10(%rbp),%rax
530ce103c:   48 83 c0 01             add    $0x1,%rax
530ce1040:   5d                      pop    %rbp
530ce1041:   c3                      retq
530ce1042:   90                      nop
<Everything between these two instructions is just more no-ops>
530ce104f:   90                      nop
```

I've been able to make this work on a Unix system, and have no troubles interfacing C DLL's with Python on that platform. Moving to Windows, however, I feel like I'm missing something. Even trying all this on a different machine, I still can't manage to get access to the function I've written.

I feel like I'm missing something here. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some fiddling, I figured out what was going on.

The function indeed had been written correctly,  compiled into a DLL correctly, and the ctypes.CDLL object created correctly.

The ctypes.CDLL object did not immediately "see" the function name, hence why it was not in the list of methods. What I did was to ignore the fact that the method was not in the object's namespace, I took a leap of faith and called `_addone.addone(x)`. This made the object realize that the function is in the DLL, and it is added into the namespace.

I suspect there is some back-end going on within ctypes, where calling a function causes it to check whether that name actually exists in the library. Perhaps this is to prevent the namespace from being cluttered by the various other functions the compiler places into the DLL.

Answer (score 1):

Try exporting the function:

```
#include "addone.h"

EXPORT long int addone(long int x){
    return x+1;
}
```

and making header file `addone.h`:

```
#define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)

EXPORT long int addone(long int x);
```